# How to recombine document pages stored as separate Base64 strings in FileNet using VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, merge, document, tiff, filenet

I have a document that is stored on FileNet. Each page of the document is stored as a separate base 64 encoded string. I need to get all of these pages into a single document again.

What I have attempted to do is to decode the Base64 string into an array. for each page of the document, I decode the Base64 string into a byte array using concatenation. I then use the [File.WriteAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes?view=netframework-4.8) method to create a single file. This file is a valid TIFF file and I am able to open it however only the last page appears. I have checked to make sure that the application I am using to open the document is capable of showing more than one page. I am using the Windows Photos application which will show all pages of a TIFF document.

How can I merge the pages of this document so that each page will appear correctly?

For example, the code below reads the Base64 string for each file and then combines them into a single output file. When I open bytefileout3.tiff however, I can only see the last page that was added into the document.

```
    Dim inputPath As String = "C:\temp\file1.txt"
    Dim fileStr As String = File.ReadAllText(inputPath)
    Dim bytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(fileStr)

    Dim inputPath2 As String = "C:\temp\file2.txt"
    Dim fileStr2 As String = File.ReadAllText(inputPath2)
    Dim bytes2 As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(fileStr2)

    Dim bytes3 As Byte() = New Byte() {}

    File.WriteAllBytes("c:\temp\bytefileout.tiff", bytes)
    File.WriteAllBytes("c:\temp\bytefileout2.tiff", bytes2)

    bytes3 = bytes2.Concat(bytes).ToArray()


    File.WriteAllBytes("c:\temp\bytefileout3.tiff", bytes3)
```

Comment: Show us the code that broke the document apart in the first place

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to that code.

Comment: You cannot patch together the byte arrays. If these are distinct TIFF Bitmaps, you can create a new TIFF container and [SaveAdd()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.saveadd) the Frames using a TIFF Encoder and specifying [SaveFlag](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.saveflag) parameters: at least an [EncoderValue.MultiFrame](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encodervalue) and `EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage` (`CompressionLZW` to compress it) (not all existing parameters are enumerated).

Comment: But, you didn't say whether these *images* are actually Pages of a multipage TIFF extracted and saved as single pages for some reason, or these are instead distinct Bitmaps (with, possibly, different resolution, Dpi, color space etc.) that need *treatment before they can be merged into a single TIFF container.

Comment: After getting a better handle on the situation, here is what I have found: TIFF documents are scanned into FileNet; PDF come in from an electronic submission process. The best way to combine these TIFF documents (for my requirements) appears to be converting each one to a PDF and then combining those PDFs into a single PDF document.